# Getting value of a dynamically created select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Apologies if my question is a little badly worded but I am not quite sure how to ask it correctly.

I am using PHP to dynamically generate some selects and I was just wondering if it is possible to do this?

Or would I need to add something like `{onChange="some_function();"}` to each of the selects, passing some variable(s) to id it ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('Selects ID or class').change(function(event) {
        $.post('formupdate.php', { selected: $('Selects ID or class').val() },
            function(data) {
                $('update the div linked to select').html(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>

<p>Q1</p>
<select name="Q1select" id="Q1select" class="Q1">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="type1">Type One</option>
    <option value="type2">Type Two</option>
    <option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update1" class="Q1"></div>
<p>Q2</p>
<select name="Q2select" id="Q2select" class="Q2">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="type1">Type One</option>
    <option value="type2">Type Two</option>
    <option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update2" class="Q2"></div>
<p>Q3</p>
<select name="Q3select" id="Q3select" class="Q3">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="type1">Type One</option>
    <option value="type2">Type Two</option>
    <option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update3" class="Q3"></div>
```

---

Updated working script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.question').change(function (event) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $.post('formupdate.php', { selected:$this.val() },
                function (data) {
                    $('#' + $this.data('div')).html(data);
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Updated html :

```
<select name="select_Q1" id="select_Q1" class="question" data-div="update_Q1">
   <option value="-">-</option>
   <option value="type1">Type One</option>
   <option value="type2">Type Two</option>
   <option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update_Q1"></div>
<p>Q2</p>
<select name="select_Q2" id="select_Q2" class="question" data-div="update_Q2">
   <option value="-">-</option>
   <option value="type1">Type One</option>
   <option value="type2">Type Two</option>
   <option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update_Q2"></div>
<p>Q3</p>
<select name="select_Q3" id="select_Q3" class="question" data-div="update_Q3">
   <option value="-">-</option>
   <option value="type1">Type One</option>
   <option value="type2">Type Two</option>
   <option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update_Q3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! If I had the rep I would mark up the other answers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that would work ... but you could simplify a touch :

```
$('Selects ID or class').change(function(event) {
    $.post('formupdate.php', { selected: $(this).val() },
        function(data) {
            $('update the div linked to select').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

changed the selector within the function to `$(this)` instead of a class or `id` that way it will work when you use on multiple elements

To link the select to a `div` you could either name the `div` similar to the `select` ie `select` `id` = `select_1` and `div` = `div_1` or use the `data` property

```
<select name="Q2select" id="Q2select" data-div="divid" class="Q2">
```

then within your AJAX callback you can do :

```
$('#' + $(this).data('div')).html(data);
```

this will set the HTML content of the `div` with the `id` = `divid` ... just an idea

### Update

there are a couple of things to try and debug this, first :

```
function (data) {
    $('#update_Q3').html(data);
}
```

this puts the content in a `div` - this checks the content returned from the `post` is working and that you can insert HTML at this point

and try this :

```
function (data) {
    alert($(this).data('div'));
}
```

this will confirm your selecting the correct `div` by getting the `data`

### Update 2

My screw up !!!!! `$(this)` is not working in the callback, try this :

```
$('.question').change(function (event) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $.post('formupdate.php', { selected:$(this).val() },
         function (data) {
             $('#' + $this.data('div')).html(data);
         }
      );
});
```

we save `$(this)` into a variable `$this` for later use

Comment: I still need to use $('select[id$=select]') on the first line of jquery yeah?

Comment: you can use whatever you want to select a single or multiple `select` lists, if you use a class that they all share then you only need one of the `change` statements

Comment: Might of been as I changed to your answer? I managed to get an ajax response using this but still not able to update the div, sorry if I am missing something obvious, I updated my question to show the new script.

Comment: @bdjohnson what errors are you getting ? have you used something like firebug to see if the content is being sent from your backend on the POST request ?

Comment: the script error was a paste error by me, in firebug I see the Post and the Response and HTML is there but the content of the div is not updated. Pretty sure I have implemented your idea incorrectly for selecting which div needs to be updated. I updated the question to show the new html too.

Comment: @mansel $('#update_Q3').html(data); works but the alert returns undefined. Guessing thats due to my html?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an event handler to all the select elements using the following:

```
 $('select').change(function(event) {
       ....
    });
​
```

In the event handler, you can get the value of the select using:

```
 $(this).val()
```

To get the ID of the select in the event handler, you can use;

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do

```
//For every select whose id ends with select
$('select[id$=select]').change(function(event) {
    //getthe id so that you can post it
    var id = this.id;
    //save the variable this to another one to use in the callback
    var that = this;
    //post the selected value and thew id of the select
    $.post('formupdate.php', { selected: $(this).val(), id : id },
        function(data) {
            update the next element after the select
            $(that).next().html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear in my question but what would I need to do to update the contents of the div under the chosen select?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, using a class of `question` on each `<select>` and using the `id` as the unique identifier. The benefit of using a class to grab the selects is if you ever add any other select to the page, they won't be affected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.question').change(function(event) {
        $.post('formupdate.php', { selected: $(this).val() },
            function(data) {

                // lets find the div that matches this question and update it
                var questionNum = $(this).attr('id').replace('select_Q', '');
                var divId = 'update_Q' + questionNum;

                $('#' + divId).html(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>

<p>Q1</p>
<select name="select_Q1" id="select_Q1" class="question">
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="type1">Type One</option>
<option value="type2">Type Two</option>
<option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update_Q1"></div>

<p>Q2</p>
<select name="select_Q2" id="select_Q2" class="question">
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="type1">Type One</option>
<option value="type2">Type Two</option>
<option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update_Q2"></div>

<p>Q3</p>
<select name="select_Q3" id="select_Q3" class="question">
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="type1">Type One</option>
<option value="type2">Type Two</option>
<option value="type3">Type Three</option>
</select>
<div id="update_Q3"></div>
```